# Variant type k has no constructor S

Tags: types, ocaml

I am trying to write an implementation for parallel prefix scan using the message passing interface module with the following signature

```
module type S = sig
  type ('s, 'r) channel
  val spawn : (('r, 's) channel -> 'a -> unit) -> 'a -> ('s, 'r) channel
  val send : ('s, 'r) channel -> 's -> unit
  val receive : ('s, 'r) channel -> 'r
  val wait_die : ('s, 'r) channel -> unit
end

module Mpi : S
```

Using the Mpi module I write an implementation for parallel prefix scan.

```
val scan: ('a -> 'a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a t -> 'a t

type 'a t = 'a array
type 'a receive_message = Seq of 'a t | Kill
type 'a ctree = Leaf of 'a * 'a | Node of 'a ctree * 'a * 'a * 'a ctree
type 'a down_incoming = In of  'a ctree * 'a | Kill

let scan (f: 'a -> 'a -> 'a) (base: 'a) (seq: 'a t) : 'a t =
  let rec up_handler ch () =
    let rec aux () =
      match Mpi.receive ch with
        Kill -> ()
      | Seq s ->  (
        let n = length s in
          match n with
            0 -> failwith "error usage"
          | 1 -> Mpi.send ch (Leaf (nth s 0,base)); aux ()
          | _ ->
            let mid = n / 2 in
            let l,r = Mpi.spawn up_handler (), Mpi.spawn up_handler () in
            Mpi.send l (Seq (Array.sub s 0 mid));Mpi.send r (Seq (Array.sub s mid (n - mid)));
            let result = (
              match (Mpi.receive l, Mpi.receive r) with
                (Leaf (lacc,_) as l_ans), (Leaf (racc,_) as r_ans) -> Node (l_ans,f lacc racc,base,r_ans)
              | (Leaf (lacc,_) as l_ans), (Node (_,racc,_,_) as r_ans) -> Node (l_ans,f lacc racc,base,r_ans)
              | (Node (_,lacc,_,_) as l_ans), (Leaf (racc,_) as r_ans) -> Node (l_ans,f lacc racc,base,r_ans)
              | (Node (_,lacc,_,_) as l_ans), (Node (_,racc,_,_) as r_ans) -> Node (l_ans,f lacc racc,base,r_ans)
            ) in
            Mpi.send ch result;Mpi.send l Kill;Mpi.send r Kill;
            Mpi.wait_die l;Mpi.wait_die r; aux () )
    in aux ()
  in
  let rec down_handler ch () =
    let rec aux () =
      match Mpi.receive ch with
        Kill -> ()
      | In (Leaf (acc,_), p) -> Mpi.send ch (singleton (f p acc)); aux ()
      | In (Node ( ( (Leaf (lacc,_) | Node (_,lacc,_,_)) as left),acc,_,right), p) ->
        let l, r = Mpi.spawn down_handler (), Mpi.spawn down_handler () in
        Mpi.send l (In (left, p));Mpi.send r (In (right,f p lacc));
        let l_ans, r_ans = Mpi.receive l, Mpi.receive r in
        let _ = Mpi.send l Kill, Mpi.send r Kill in
        Mpi.wait_die l;Mpi.wait_die r;
        let result = (append l_ans r_ans) in
        Mpi.send ch result; aux ()
    in aux ()
  in
  match length seq with
    0 -> [||]
  | _ ->
    let up_ch = Mpi.spawn up_handler () in
    Mpi.send up_ch (Seq seq);
    let up_ans = Mpi.receive up_ch in
    let _ = Mpi.send up_ch Kill in
    Mpi.wait_die up_ch;
    let down_ch = Mpi.spawn down_handler () in
    Mpi.send down_ch (In (up_ans,base));
    let down_ans  = Mpi.receive down_ch in
    let _ = Mpi.send down_ch Kill in
    Mpi.wait_die down_ch;
    down_ans
```

When I try to compile I get the error 
"Error: The variant type down_incoming has no constructor Seq" which doesn't make sense as it should be matching with the 'receive_message' type instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both your types have a constructor `Kill`, the last one is used by default in a pattern matching. So when traversing your `up_handler` and your `aux` functions, as `ch`'s type is not yet inferred, it is (wrongly) deduced that it has type `down_incoming`.

Workarounds:

- Change your pattern matching order (handle `Seq` before `Kill`).
- Unify `ch` with type `receive_message` manually (`let rec up_handler (ch:receive_message) () = ...`).
- Give different names to your constructors.

Note that as those three solution will produce the same code, it's really up to you to choose your favorite way (mine would be the second).

Comment: Thanks PatJ, how come the OCaml compiler is not able to infer this during compilation?

Comment: This may be in some cases really hard. Asking the user to disambiguate himself is a good workaround. Also, the feature is quite new to the language and may be improved to handle better the noticed use-cases.

Comment: You'll get a warning when using duplicate variants with warning 41. starting the compiler with `ocaml -w +41` will provide it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Kill` is first in the matching and will infer the type to be the latest type with that variant. Switch the order and you will be fine.

```
  match Mpi.receive ch with
  | Seq s -> ...
  | Kill -> ()
  ...
  match Mpi.receive ch with
  | In (Leaf (acc,_), p) -> ...
  |  Kill -> ()
```

Instead of using Kill like this in two places, you should consider an `option` around the `In` or `Seq` type parameters.

```
type 'a receive_message = 'a t option
type 'a down_incoming   = ('a ctree * 'a) option
```